# When will an app pool with both time intervals and a specific time recycle?

Tags: iis, asp.net, application-pools

Am I correct in assuming an application pool with recycle settings of:

- regular time interval: 1740
- Specific time: 3:00AM

will only reset at 3:00AM, because the time interval is over 24 hours?

Answer (score 2):

On IIS 8.5 (Windows 8.1), I've just run the following test.

My start time is **11:04**.  I set the app pool to recycle at **11:06** (specific time), and also reset every **5 minutes** (regular time interval).

Using PowerShell -

```
ps w3wp | select ProcessName, StartName
```

First, when checking the start date of the process, I get **11:04:27** (The time when I changed the settings of the app pool, forcing a recycle).

Then, I get **11:06:00** (when the specific time passes).

I let time go on.  The next change is at **11:11:00**.  This is 5 minutes from when the last specific time recycle kicked in.

So, all in all, the regular time interval counter is reset when the specific time passes.

TL;DR

In the given question, the app pool will reset at 3.00am every day, because the 1740 minutes always gets cut short by the specific time recycles.

Answer (score 0):

That is my understanding as well. The time interval counter would be reset each night at 3:00AM and will never reach its 29 hours threshold.

I can't find any official information about this though. To confirm this assumption turn on event logging and let it run for a few days. Events should be in the `Application Event Log` with the source `WAS`